# Ragarding ruby on rails sessions

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my rails application, I'm using a devise gem for user sign in and sign out.

After a successful sign in, I want to store data in the user's session. How can I do this?

Comment: Surely this question has been answered before? What have you tried so far? What specifically are you trying to store? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i trying to store the selected radio button into the user session

Comment: i do know where and how to write the session code for storing the value of radio button

Comment: you can get who has logged in by current_user. so from above answer some data which you getting from radio button you need to store along with user session ??

Comment: yes praaveen thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

To verify if a user is signed in, use the following helper:

```
user_signed_in?
```

For the current signed-in user, this helper is available:

```
current_user
```

You can access the session for this scope:

```
user_session
```

As you mentioned need to add data to session code goes here

adding this to my config/initializers/devise.rb file

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.raw_session['warden.user.user.email'] = user.email
  auth.raw_session['warden.user.user.username'] = user.username
end
```

Comment: how can i use there hepler and where to use these

Comment: because i am new in rails thats why i did not know

Comment: refer this blog  http://www.jackiejohnston.us/blog/setting-up-user-authentication-with-devise/  will help to understand.

Comment: other nice blog for devise  http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication

Comment: Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.raw_session['warden.user.user.email'] = user.email
  auth.raw_session['warden.user.user.username'] = user.username
end

Comment: Devise Flexible authentication solution for Rails with Warden. so check your gemlock file warden is installed while devise gem is installed.

Comment: refer this github page will give you complete info https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.

Comment: is there any need use session variable in the controller

Comment: I you want you can override

Override the Devise sessions controller actions:

# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def edit
    # add custom logic here
    @num_of_cars = current_user.num_of_cars.all 
    super
  end

end 

Register the controller:

# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}

Comment: but devise does not create any type of cotroller yet?? no sessions controller etc so how can i use this devise creatred already sessions then why we need sessions controller

Comment: if user_signed_in?
                session[:question] = Question.find_by(params[:question_id])
                session[:selected_answer] = params[:submit_answer]
            end

Comment: i write code in mycontroller action is it workable or not

Comment: you need to override by creating sessions_controller.rb

Comment: current_user, user_signed_in? etc.. you can use it controller and views as well.

Comment: i got that error   ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow                                                     how can i resolve this

Comment: can i directly pass selected radio button in the sessionsw